# DisplayNameFor tag change text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have following code in my Details View of Entity A

```
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User1.UserName)
</dt>
<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User1.UserName)
</dd>
```

I want to change their title that is shown in Details View
it is showing UserName where i want it to be Submitted by
it cant be overloaded because DisplayName For donot have any overloaded function with two params
`@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User1.UserName,"Submitted By")` Not working
any Help

Here is my Model of Bugs Where i have Fields of Assigned to and submitted by which are related to the users model so i am having problem that "UserName" is shown at the place of column Name where it should show the Names as "Assigned To" and "Submitted By"

```
    public partial class Bug
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string Severity { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public int SubmittedBy { get; set; }
    public int ComponentID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BugNumber { get; set; }
    public string NormalFlow { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Component Component { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can control the displayed text via the **[Display]** attribute on your model.  In your case you'd want to set the attribute on the underlying model for User1:

```
public class User
{
   [Display(Name = "Submitted By")]
   public string UserName;
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more details on the DisplayAttribute class.

Comment: i am new in asp.net so i want to new that which class is this is this the the class that is available in model that i have imported from my custom SQL database if yes then it is not working.

Comment: and i am working in mvc not .aspx web forms thank you in advance

Comment: Edit your post to add the code for your model class and we can have another look.

Comment: I hope i have explained my problem

Comment: Is there any reason you **must** use DisplayNameFor instead of simply hard-coding the label?

Comment: What I'm asking, do you have a strong reason not to do this: `<dt>
    Submitted By
</dt>
<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User1.UserName)
</dd>`

Answer (score 10):

As long as you want to change the displayed text of a label no need to change your model..
**just edit your Razor View like this:**

```
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayName("Submitted By")
</dt>
<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User1.UserName)
</dd>
```

**OR**

```
<dt>
        Submitted By
 </dt>
 <dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User1.UserName)
 </dd>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one that is working for me.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.category_type_id, "Category Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```